# Screen Sharing from Mac (vnc client) into PC (vnc server) on local network

Tags: windows, imac, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

On my iMac (running 10.13.6) I would like to view the desktop of my PC (running Win10 & tightvnc server).

Here is what i tried;
Finder > Go > Connect to Server > "vnc://AsusRog:6666"


I get the error;
"Unable to resolve “AsusRog:6666".
"Verify the name you entered and make sure your network connection is working."


note:
I configured tightvnc server on my PC to use port 6666


note:
i have two PCs on the same local network as my imac, and i can use either PC to view the other PCs desktop using tightvnc server & tightvnc viewer (or realvnc viewer). I can also use either PC (running realvnc or tightvnc viewer) to view the desktop of my iMac by simply entering in my iMacs network name (and vnc port) into realvnc or tightvnc viewer on the PC.


note:
all my PCs and my one iMac which are on the same local network can share files. for instance, using any of my PCs i can access files on my mac. And using my iMac i can access any files on either of my PCs by simply do the following on my iMac;
Finder > Go > Connect to Server > "smb://myPcName"


note:
i can use my iMac to remote desktop (screen share) into my mothers computer which is outside my local network by doing the following;
Finder > Go > Connect to Server > "vnc://username:password@ip.add.re.ss:portnumber".

Question;
  
Am i using the wrong syntax to connect locally from my iMac to my PC named AsusRog running tighvnc server and port 6666? 
 
Finder > Go > Connect to Server > "vnc://AsusRog:6666"

thank you for your time.

Comment: The error “Unable to resolve” means your Mac can’t find an IP address for that name. Try connecting with the IP address instead

Comment: I assume you have the Home edition of Windows 10. If not, then why not use Microsoft Remote Desktop? This is a free product from Microsoft.

Comment: @Allen ... using the local ip address worked, thank you....but why would vnc need to connect using an IP address and not the computer name? i mean, both computers are on the same local network and smb://computername file sharing works fine with just the computer name (and not the ip address)...anyways, thanks again.

Comment: @David Anderson - thank u for your reply.. i was only recently aware of Microsoft remote desktop....  however it will not work on macos 10.13 (it requires 10.14 or above).. and regarding my PC, yes i have the home edition of Win10 and for 2 years i was using tightvnc & realvnc successfully so i didnt think to look for another vnc client/server and i never knew MS remote desktop app existed, all i knew was that remote desktop was disabled for Win10Home. i mean,why did MS disable it then end up releasing it as an app that you have to download and install on win10home? seems roundabout to me.